# Providing default value to Input In SAP Hana procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, hana, hana-studio

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Hana Studio. In the stored procedure ,I am trying to give a default value to the input. my code is,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE defaultSchemaName.procedureName (IN INPUT NVARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'TEST')
```

This runs fine when I am trying to create a `.hdbprocedure` but fails when I want to create a `.procedure`.
Is there any way to use a default procedure in Design Time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in SAP Hana as the .procedure artifact is now depricated and there would be no support for this artifact.
However one way of solving this problem is to convert the .procedure to .HDBprocedure(simply change the design-time artifact template and changes the type of artifact to .hdbprocedure).
In .hdbprocedure we can assign a default value to an input variable.